# Configure Canon LBP6200 to print

Tags: printing, canon

I've configured my LBP6200 printer with Ubuntu and Canon drivers and each time I print a test page, the job status --> printed completed but nothing prints and printer is powered on, in active/ready mode.

I have this machine setup as a dual boot with printing working on the Windows OS.

I have tried:

1. Printer Settings > Printer Details > Search for drivers > hangs or returns nothing
2. Printer Settings > Printer Details > Select from Database… > select Canon LBP6200 CAPT (UK) or Canon LBP6200 CAPT (UK) (both titled the same)
3. Printer Settings > Printer Details > Install PPD File… > select file:///usr/share/ppd/CNCUPSLBP6200CAPTK.ppd
4. Printer Settings > Remove printer > Add… → Ubuntu detect the printer automatically as CUPS-BRF-Printer with Generic Text-Only Printer
5. http://localhost:631/

I have read a few pages from other frustrated users and the answers usually involve a sequence of magic terminal commands and no why that I can extrapolate to my particular setup (ptr, ubu ver, etc).

Can anyone suggest why I've failed so far?

I'm new to linux as you may have guessed but I see this as a way to learn Linux - after all, what we do everyday is solve puzzles :)

----------------- EDIT -------------------------

RTFM, ok probably a good call.

CANONver.2.7x Online Manual Installation

I removed printer before starting from Printer Settings.

- "cndrvcups-common_x.xx-x_amd64.deb" : common module for CUPS drivers
- "cndrvcups-capt_x.xx-x_amd64.deb" : CAPT printer driver module
- Start Linux after installation, and log in as 'root'
- sudo -i : Install the common module for CUPS driver.
- dpkg -i /home/barnyard/Downloads/linux-capt-drv-v271-usen/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb : Install the CAPT printer driver module
- dpkg -i /home/barnyard/Downloads/linux-capt-drv-v271-usen/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
- cups restart : Register the printer service
- /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP6200D -P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP6200CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 -E : Register the printer (PPD) with the print spooler
- /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP7200C -o /dev/usb/lp0 : Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file (USB Connection)
- /etc/init.d/ccpd start : Start ccpd daemon

I then went to printer settings and did a test print - nothing. I note a new printer being added by system (as printer powered on). A test page on this printer also fails! :(

Comment: You didn't mention that you consulted with the documentation for your device.  This should be your first step if hardware is not automatically installed.  I see that the manufacturer publishes a [linux driver](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/lbp6200d/imageclass-lbp6200d?tab=drivers_downloads) for the device.  I suggest consulting with their documentation on how to install it. FYI: To improve your chances of getting an answer, you should share your research with us -- we don't believe in "magical" terminal commands ;)

Comment: RTFM, ok probably a good call. I followed the instructions to the letter but no joy. I summarised the instructions but I'm limited in in adding a comment here.